# How can I know who owns certain pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

I am writing a personal project where I have players drawing cards from a deck. Then the player activates the card (there are different types of cards, each with a different effect), and finally he returns the card to the bottom of the deck.

So far I have managed to draw the card from the deck and store it in my player. Lets imagine I have only two types of cards:

```cpp
class card
{
public:
    virtual void activate() = 0;
};

class moveAnywhere : public card
{
public:
    virtual void activate();
};

class bonusQuestion : public card
{
public:
    virtual void activate();
};
```

Then I have my deck (where player is a friend):

```cpp
class deck
{
private:
    std::queue<std::unique_ptr<card>> cards;
public:
    friend class player;
};
```

And finally my player:

```cpp
class player
{
private:
    std::list<std::unique_ptr<card>> usableCards;
public:
    void drawCard(deck&);
};


void player::drawCard(deck& theDeck)
{
    usableCards.push_back(std::unique_ptr<card>(std::move(theDeck.cards.front())));
    theDeck.cards.pop();
}
```

This way I have managed to take the first card from the deck, and store it into my player's hand. But my problem is how activate and return cards to the deck.

1) Would it be better to `card::activate(player&)` so that I know who activated the card (which seems weird as the card belongs to the player, so there shouldn't be a need to specify that).

2) Would it be better to add a private member to the cards e.g. `player owner;` and everytime somebody draws a card it assigns an owner to the card.

3) Or how can I activate the cards from within the player, and use that player in the effects of the card.

4)What is the logical way of returning the card to the deck? Should that be a method of the card, the player, the deck?

I believe I am overcomplicating the situation, I am just confused and need a little push into the right direction.

Comment: I would be tempted to have a `player::take_turn()` function and give the players access to the pack so they can draw, activate and return their own cards.

Comment: Probably more suited to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) than here.  This looks pretty over-complicated.  Think about what your objects represent and what interactions they have with other objects.  If "activating" a card changes a property of the card itself, then do that.  If instead it gives the player some special "effect", then maybe you are missing some classes (such as `effect`) and that's why you're confused.

Comment: This is more of a 'code review/opinion' kind of question, which isn't really SO's MO. IMO, though, if the only time a card needs to know its owner is when it is activated, then option 1 seems the best. If that's not the case... well, you know how they'll be used, so you're the one to best judge and decide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawing from real-life intuition, when it comes time for a human card player to return a card to the deck, you would typically ask the player to play the card and then place it back in the deck (as opposed to the more unusual scenario where the card places itself back in the deck without the player's involvement -- that would usually be reserved for magic tricks :))

Therefore, I would go with something like:

```
std::unique_ptr<card> player :: activateAndReturnCard()
{
   // code for the player-object to choose a card to
   // remove from his hand, activate it, and then return it
}
```

... Then the deck class (or whoever) can call the above method on the appropriate player-object and place the result back into the deck after it returns.  Given the above, having the player-object call `activate(*this);` on the card-object would be reasonable (since the card's activation-logic will presumably need to read and/or update the player-object's state somehow).

Answer (score 2):

This is very opinion based to be honest. I would probably go for something like this, giving the `player` the responsibility to play their own hand when instructed to `take_turn()` by the game controller (a loop in this example).

```
class card
{
public:
    virtual void activate() {}
};

class deck
{
private:
    std::queue<std::unique_ptr<card>> cards;

public:

    std::unique_ptr<card> draw()
    {
        auto c = std::move(cards.front());
        cards.pop();
        return c;
    }

    void put_back(std::unique_ptr<card> c)
    {
        cards.push(std::move(c));
    }
};

class player
{
private:
    deck& cards;
    std::list<std::unique_ptr<card>> hand;

    std::unique_ptr<card> select_card()
    {
        // select the best card from the hand
        // and return it

        auto c = std::move(hand.front()); // something cleverer than this!
        hand.pop_front();
        return c;
    }

public:
    player(deck& cards): cards(cards) {}


    void take_turn()
    {
        // draw a card from the deck
        auto c = cards.draw();
        hand.push_back(std::move(c));

        // select the best card to activate
        c = select_card();
        c->activate();

        // return card to deck
        cards.put_back(std::move(c));
    }
};

int main()
{
    deck cards;
    player wendy(cards);
    player bob(cards);

    while(true)
    {
        wendy.take_turn();
        bob.take_turn();
    }
}
```